# Can't render pre-made 3d model three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Can someone please give an example and explain how this work. How to render a 3d object with three.js or other libraries? This object is already made. How to render the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the exporters to save it to a JSON object: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters

Once you have your JSON object:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('obj/model.js', function(geometry, materials) {
    // Do stuff with your geometry and materials
);
```

---

You can load OBJ models too, as in this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj

You will need this script: http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total) {
    console.log(item, loaded, total);
};

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
loader.load('obj/model.obj', function(object) {
    scene.add(object);
});
```

Comment: when do you have the JSON file, where do you include it? I can't see it any where in the code.

Comment: You don't have to include it! The `JSONLoader.load()` is reading it :)